# How to create an Azure based WCF restful API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, restful-authentication

any tutorials on that?

ideally it would have basic http authentication

can I create a restful WCF web service and deploy to Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Is WCF realy needed?
There is Asp.Net WebApi now. It is successor of WCF WebApi. Here is tutorial link:
[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

And in general there is no difference in actual code for Azure or OnPremise.